How to disable "Alt" key menu navigation in Ubuntu for VS Code shortcuts
I frequently use keyboard shortcuts in VS Code to speed up my workflow. However, since switching to Ubuntu, I've noticed an issue with shortcuts that involve the "Alt" key. Every time I press and hold "Alt," the menu bar in VS Code activates, showing underlined letters as accelerators. This disrupts my ability to use shortcuts that require the "Alt" key.
[]
According to the Ubuntu documentation, the "Alt" key has a system-wide function described as follows:

Alt: Hold down the Alt key to reveal accelerators — underlined letters
on menu items, buttons, and other controls. Press Alt plus the
underlined letter to activate a control, just as if you had clicked on
it.

I'm looking for a way to disable this "Alt" key behavior or at least reassign it to a different key so that I can use "Alt" key shortcuts within VS Code without triggering the menu bar. Ideally, I'd like to achieve this without installing third-party software.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Try to set "window.menuBarVisibility": "hidden" on the "settings.json", which makes the menu always hidden, even after a keypress on the Alt key.
